# How to replace swap 2 properties for each instance inside a generic List?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I swap 2 properties from each instance inside a generic Lists. Explaining better:

I would like that BInstance1 become BInstance2 and BInstance2 become BInstance1 for all instances of A inside that List:

I am pretty sure I should be use Select linq extension method but I don't quite see the syntax for that

```
public class A
{
    public B BInstance1 { get; set; }
    public B BInstance2 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}


        var aList = new List<A>();

        aList.Add(new A()
        {
            BInstance1 = new B() { Created = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)), Id = 1, Name = "B1" },
            BInstance2 = new B() { Created = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0, 0)), Id = 2, Name = "B2" }
        });

        aList.Add(new A()
        {
            BInstance1 = new B() { Created = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0, 0)), Id = 3, Name = "B3" },
            BInstance2 = new B() { Created = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0, 0)), Id = 4, Name = "B4" }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to encapsulate this logic as part of the class. Then you could do something like this

```
public class A
{
   public B BInstance1 { get; set; }
   public B BInstance2 { get; set; }

   // deconstruction tuple swap
   public void Swap() => (BInstance1, BInstance2) = (BInstance2, BInstance1);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var aList = new List<A>();

aList.Add(new A()
{
  BInstance1 = new B() { Created = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)), Id = 1, Name = "B1" },
  BInstance2 = new B() { Created = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0, 0)), Id = 2, Name = "B2" }
});

foreach (var item in aList)
  item.Swap();
```

<sub>***Note** : Obviously this doesn't need to part of a class, it could be an extension method, and helper method, or any other variation such as being used in line*</sub>

<sub>***Note 2** : If you wanted a new allocated list and clone of the original object you will need to project (`Select`) and manually (or by other means) recrate the objects individually*</sub>

Comment: Using tuple deconstruction for swapping properties is cheating! Where are the temp variables that we had to use the good old days?...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias its the new hotness :) Temp variables begone!